# uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

1) created a model called `Skill`

2) ran some seeds

3) ran `rspec --init`

4) created file `skill_spec.rb` with the code below

```
require_relative "../app/models/skill"

describe Skill do
  describe "database" do
    it "should have 42 skills" do
      expect(Skill.all.count).to eq(42)
    end
  end
end
```

5) when I run `rspec` in console get error:

> Failure/Error: class Skill < ApplicationRecordNameError: 
>   uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord

I already have a file `application_record.rb` with the following code

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

Comment: you shouldnt need to add `require_relative "../app/models/skill"`

Comment: add `require 'spec_helper'`

Comment: deleted the first line, added `require 'spec_helper'` and now the error is as follows:

`An error occurred while loading ./spec/skill_spec.rb.
Failure/Error:
  describe Skill do
    describe "database" do
      it "should have 42 skills" do
        expect(Skill.all.count).to eq(42)
      end
    end
  end

NameError:
  uninitialized constant Skill
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For rails specs, include `require 'rails_helper'` at beginning of each spec file (it is generated by `bin/rails generate rspec:install` from `rspec-rails` gem)

It contains line `require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)` that will load your rails environment and you'll have autoloading and all other rails parts working.